# How to show all customer grid list in our custom admin form in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to show all customer list in our custom admin form. so how to get this customer grid list in our form?

Comment: do you mean showing customer grid in custom form like in order form?

Comment: Yes @RendyEkoPrastiyo